# Teleop control not working in Turtlebot Simulator package and Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, rviz, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

currently following the tutorial @
http:// [www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world)

Everything else seems to work fine. The model loads into gazebo and the pointclooud image can be seen in Rviz. But I cannot control the turtlebot using the teleop keyboard configuration.

I'm using the newest Gazebo(1.9) and ros Hydro is installed.

If I try to use the $ roslaunch kobuki_keyop keyop.launch command it tells me Keyop can not connect. I'm not sure if they've started on different servers and are unable to communicate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74908/teleop-control-not-working-in-turtlebot-simulator-package-and-gazebo/) by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you are using Hydro sources, I commited a fix for the turtlebot teleop on monday, so a git pull on turtlebot_simulator should fix it.

Kobuki keyop also should work if you have all the latest code. The "could not connect" warning appears because before the enable/disable commands where not simulated on Gazebo, but they are now.

Please also ensure you use the latest Gazebo and SDF versions.

If you don't wont to mangle with code, all these changes will be released together with the official Hydro release.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-08-27**:
No, don't wait!  :-) Get the sources, test it and let us know what's not working.
This will help us polishing the code for the release!

**Comment by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on 2013-08-27**:
I'll definitely give it a go. How hard can it be, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same versions, and this command works for me. The kobuki keyop gives me the same error. Did you try this?

roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch

---

Originally posted by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) with karma: 275 on 2013-08-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-08-27**:
Also make sure that the window for the teleop command is selected when trying to control the robot, otherwise it won't get the key events.

**Comment by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on 2013-08-27**:
Yes "roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch" is what I tried first and the terminal window was active.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-10**:
@Alkaros, Are you correctly able to move the TurtleBot in the Gazebo environment? I have downloaded the code from [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator). But inside the code I have not find anything regarding the publishing or advertising into a topic. In gazebo can we construct a maze?

**Comment by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on 2013-11-10**:
You'll also need to install ros-hydro-turtlebot-apps. http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world. You can see thee published topics using "rostopic list". Also for the maze. http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Building_Editor